# Centering translated div inside div (css logo)

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

I'm experimenting with a logo in css. I build this with different div's.
The logo contains two parts, the right and the left part. Each part contains two div's with the 2d- front material and one with the 3d extrusion parts. These last two are each split up into an upper and a lower div.

I made the logo bigger than it is supposed to so I translated the outer div to the correct size. I wasn't able to set the measurements of that outer div to automatically wrap the translated div container, so I did this manually.

I want to add this css logo into a horizontal navigation list, one of the item's needs to contain this logo.

I'm breaking my head on how to align this div in the center of my list item. I searched for it but I can't seem to find a descent solution. Can someone put me in the right direction ? It would be much appreciated !
---> I gave the div main-nav-logo tbe same size as my list item, now I want to accomplish that I get the logo div in the center of the main-nav-logo div ...

```css
.main-nav-logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  /* for testing purpose */
  height: 144px;
  /* for testing purpose */
  text-align: center;
  /* for testing purpose */
  margin-left: auto;
  /* for testing purpose */
  margin-right: auto;
  /* for testing purpose */
  float: left;
  /* for testing purpose */
  overflow: auto;
  /* for testing purpose */
  padding: 0px;
  display: table;
  /* for testing purpose */
  clear: both;
  /* for testing purpose */
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: -110px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* for testing purpose */
  margin-right: auto;
  /* for testing purpose */
  -moz-transform: scale(0.351);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.351);
  -o-transform: scale(0.351);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.351);
  transform: scale(0.351);
}
.left-cap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.right-cap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
}
.left-cap-front {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-cap-extrusion {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -102%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.right-cap-front {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.right-cap-extrusion {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.left-cap-front-upper {
  position: absolute;
}
.left-cap-front-lower {
  position: absolute;
}
.left-cap-extrusion-upper {
  position: absolute;
}
.left-cap-extrusion-lower {
  position: absolute;
}
.right-cap-front-upper {
  position: absolute;
}
.right-cap-front-lower {
  position: absolute;
}
.right-cap-extrusion-upper {
  position: relative;
}
.right-cap-extrusion-lower {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav-logo">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="left-cap">
      <div class="left-cap-front">
        <div class="left-cap-front-upper">
        </div>
        <div class="left-cap-front-lower">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="left-cap-extrusion">
        <div class="left-cap-extrusion-upper">
        </div>
        <div class="left-cap-extrusion-lower">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-cap">
      <div class="right-cap-front">
        <div class="right-cap-front-upper">
        </div>
        <div class="right-cap-front-lower">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-cap-extrusion">
        <div class="right-cap-extrusion-upper">
        </div>
        <div class="right-cap-extrusion-lower">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hoping for some insight ... (Also if it means that I will have to rewrite the whole thing)

Thanks in advance !

A screenshot from the above code in JSFiddle gives me :
[logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpzXK.png)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hotozu/2/edit?html,css,js,output Nice logo

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that bin seems blank for me (tried firefox and safari)

Comment: Seems blank to me too, but I like *white* logos. P.S: it's the exact same code you shared with us and I tried to give a meaning to your question and recreating your issue.

Comment: So now, if you share some code and that code reproduces > nothing > How do you think one could easily answer your question without losing another 15 minutes deciphering it?

Comment: I removed the size's, colors and transformations of the the divs with absolute positioning, which are the logo ... Do you need these ? Hold on, I will edit my first post ---> I added all the parts, please recheck ?

Comment: do you have an image of what you want to achieve, so we can post our own idea in it...

Now all i get is blank screen...

Comment: I have added all the code together with a screenshot of the above code in jsfiddle. Is it more clear now ?

Comment: On first sight it seems you have quite some redundancy in your HTML. Many divs for what you actually need. Also, it might be easier/more efficient to use an SVG image for this.

Comment: Hi Bram, thank you for your insight, fellow country man. I did this because I want to build some animation in parts of the logo afterwards. I could accomplish this by adding classes but I don't see that will help my issue ? To center the logo-div in the main-nav-logo-div ... Indeed I have a working template with an svg build in, placed as a background. But I'm hoping for a solution with the logo styled in css because I want to animate it ...